# Issues on Excel big files using Java

Tags: java, excel

I have to handle a big Excel (.xlsx) report file (data size goes from 300.000 to 1.000.000 entries with 50 fields) made of text, currency, and timestamps.

The process I'm using right know is a bit tricky but functional:

1. I execute a pretty complex query on my Oracle db
2. Data elaboration is done by finance classes
3. Parsed String results are temporary stored into a matrix
4. My ExcelManager class reads matrix and then writes strings on a .csv file (tab separated)
5. I later convert this .csv file in a .xlsx file - if file exceeds 300.000 rows size I split it in multiple sheets or multiple files, depending on user preference - and yes, I have a compatibility message every time user opens this .xlsx but this is not an issue.

This process became necessary because I encountered memory and performance issues (OutOfMemoryError Exception / hours waiting for my file) when I tried generating this kind of big Excel reports with other classes (based on Apache POI or jxl).

Now, user wants to add formattation on these big files (colored header, merged regions), the problem is that I can't perform formattation as a normal .xls / .xlsx file using POI/jxl methods, since I build it from a .csv text file.

I can't use products like: https://www.oraexcel.com (I have no budget)

It is possibile to generate Excel reports with a PL/SQL procedure and I already tried to, it works (haven't tested with big amount of data yet) but

is PL/SQL able to format cell style/ merge cells?
Also, is this procedure any way faster than Apache POI/jxl lib?

If you apoted another solution which doesn't involve PL/SQL or POI I'm absolutely open to new possibilities!

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understood what you're meaning, but maybe you could try the streaming version of apache-poi (SXSSFWorkbook)

Comment: I tried every kind of workbook in my ExcelManager classes: HSSF, SSF and XSSF. Performances are way too slow and unfortunately I can't wait hours for this report to be generated (even if it's a scheduled task, I need it to be excecuted as fast as possible)

Comment: I meant SXSSF. The streaming version. For sure you won't have memory problems. I'm not sure about the performance.

Comment: I misread there, gonna read about SXSSF tho

Comment: Ok I'm reading about that, seems like a resolution to my problem, I'm trying to implement it in my code